# How to make vue-cli-service fail if one of the process.env.VUE_APP_* environment vars cannot be resolved

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, environment-variables, vue-cli-3

I am using environment variables in my code as explained in the [vue-cli-service environment variables section](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code), and it surely works when the environment variables are defined.

But when one of the environment variables is undefined, it just replaces it with undefined.

Let's say if I introduce a new `process.env.VUE_APP_MY_NEW_VAR`, but then I don't set it in the environment, it will just put an `undefined` there.

I wanted to be sure that when building the project (`npx vue-cli-service build [...]`), none of the environment variables remain undefined.

One of my ideas is to check for `undefined` always, but it would happen at run time, not compile time.

Another idea is to create a shell script to check that all the variables are set before building, but that sounds quite manual.

Is there a way to do configure it and make it part of the build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a check in `vue.config.js`. For example

```js
const REQUIRED_ENV_VARS = [
  'VUE_APP_VAR_1',
  'VUE_APP_VAR_2'
]

if (REQUIRED_ENV_VARS.some(env => typeof process.env[env] === 'undefined')) {
  throw new Error('Required environment variables are missing')
}
```